# get the xml attribute value using xslt tree wise

Tags: xslt

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="try.xsl"?>
<oneday>
    <team1 id="1" team="India">
        <team2 id="2" team="gujarat">
            <team3 id="3" team="guj11"></team3>
        </team2>
    </team1>
</oneday>
```

This is my xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my output:

```
oneday
    team1
        team2
            team3
```

But I want to output something like this:

```
oneday
    team1:India
        team2:Gujarat
            team3:Guj11
```

Comment: So you just want the values of the @team attributes specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="spacing" />

    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:if test="@team">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', @team)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="spacing">
    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample XML, this produces:

```
oneday
    team1:India
        team2:gujarat
            team3:guj11
```

When run on a slightly more complex XML:

```
<oneday>
  <team1 id="1" team="India">
    <team2 id="2" team="gujarat">
      <team3 id="3" team="guj11"></team3>
    </team2>
    <team6 team="Mumbai" />
  </team1>
  <team4 team="France">
    <team5 team="Paris" />
  </team4>
</oneday>
```

It produces:

```
oneday
    team1:India
        team2:gujarat
            team3:guj11
        team6:Mumbai
    team4:France
        team5:Paris
```